# Can I take screenshot of outside of web browser in Javascript or flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, web, screenshot

I would like to know if it is possible to capture content of outside of web browser when open web page.
So for example, when use enter some website, web server can capture content of outside of web browser?
If it's possible, how can I do that?
Thank you

Comment: That sounds like a *giant* security risk. What if the client had sensitive information open on their screen? This better not be possible.

Comment: That's like saying ...  *"here [any website]...take a look at everything I got"*